# Nginx Reverse Proxy returns 403 when uploading large file

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm setting an **Nginx proxy** that forwards requests to **PHP (Laravel)** application, all using **Docker** in a **Kubernetes** cluster.

All the application is working fine except the issue below.

When I upload **small files** (images), it **works perfectly**. When I increase the uploaded file size, I get this response:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <h1>403 Forbidden</h1>
    </center>
</body>

</html>
```

**site.conf**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        index index.php index.html;
        root /var/www/public;

        location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
          gzip_static on;
          client_max_body_size 128M;
          proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass kubernetes-laravel-service:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }
    }
```

I also have an additional PHP **ini** configuration as follows:
**custom-config.ini**

```
file_uploads = On
memory_limit = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 600
```

Btw, the file sizes that I tried:

- 1 file of 7kb                     => works
- 1 file of 7kb + 1 file of 6kb     => 403
- 2 files of 2kb each               => works
- 1 file of 246kb                   => 403

**UPDATE 1:**
I updated /etc/nginx/nginx.conf as follows:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    client_max_body_size 128M;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_request_buffering off;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Still same 403 response.

Comment: are you using more than 1 server (do you have a load balancer) ? If you do, I think it is trying to balance sending the data to another server but I do not know.

Comment: @matiaslauriti The application is inside a Kubernetes cluster (behind a Load Balancer), but there is only one Nginx service, one Nginx pod, one Laravel service and one Laravel pod. So there is no balancing of workload for now.

Comment: I am not sure now if it is Laravel or Nginx throwing `403`. Can you check logs of both Laravel and Nginx?

Comment: I was not sure too.. But I pointed the Nginx to a non existing pod. When I send a request without a file I get 502 - Bad Gateway.
But when I add the file, I get 403.

Comment: Try to use `client_max_body_size 128M` on server block instead of location.

Answer (score 1):

This may require top-level settings:

```
http {
  fastcgi_buffers ...;
  fastcgi_buffer_size ...;

  http2_max_concurrent_streams ...;
  http2_chunk_size ...;

  client_max_body_size ...;

  ...
}
```

Comment: I added these lines to **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf** inside 
```http {
...
client_max_body_size 128M;
proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_request_buffering off;
...
}```

But still same 403 response

Comment: I added full nginx.conf as "update" in the question